# sql server base tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I use SQL Server 2012.

How can select from sql server [system base table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179503.aspx) such as below tables.

- sys.sysschobjs
- sys.sysbinobjs
- sys.sysclsobjs

When I get query from base system table such as below query. get following error.

```
select * from sys.sysschobjs


Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'sys.sysschobjs'.
```

Comment: Are you running the query in the Master database?

Comment: @JohnFx. Yes. I get query on master database.

Comment: are you sure. Try running USE Master before running this query.

Comment: @JohnFx. I add Use Master; above of my query. but the result of my query don't change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is doable if you used a "***Database Engine Query***", and an **administrator user**.
To do so, after you open the SQL Management Studio:
Click **File** Menu, "**New**" sub menu, and select "**Database Engine Query**".
In the server name, write "**Admin:**" before your server name (eg., if your server name is "**localhost**", then the full server name to be written is "***admin:localhost***")
Then write your credentials (for administrative account).

N.B.: Make sure that there are no other administrator logged in to the Database Engine Query  other than you (I believe it is a single access point)

For more information:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068(v=sql.105).aspx

http://zarez.net/?p=774

Answer (score 5):

To query this system base tables needs a `Dedicated Administrator Console (DAC).`

> First, connect to your database using the DAC. To do this from SQL
>   Server Management Studio, go to File -> New -> Database Engine Query.
>   Put ADMIN: in front of your instance name and click Connect.

Change to the your database using the `USE [mydb]`

Now you can query

```
select * from sys.sysschobjs
```

See this post for further info on this:

http://www.hackingsqlserver.com/

https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/08/t-sql-tuesday-24-dude-wheres-the-rest-of-my-procedure